# Store a MySQL database in source control

Tags: mysql, tfs, controls, integration

Our company mainly develops in .NET with MSSQL although there are some product that were build on PHP with MySQL. We develop in Visual Studio and store all our data under TFS Source Control. Now by default there is a database project for MSSQL but there ain't one for MySQL. Now I aspect that we are no the first people trying to store a MySQL database under TFS SC. Herefore I googled for some solutions or best practices but I did not found much helpful information.

Now we can say that we make a custom template for a MySQL project. With a directory pre-defined structure and loose files for every element TABLE, KEYS, PROC ect. On deployment let it create one large script and deploy it on the MySQL database by command-line.

The above solution doesn't seam ideal for me and that's why I searched for other solutions. Maybe there are some program's or known solutions that are better than the one I had in mind. I would appreciate it if some of you can inform me or share your knowledge or ideas with me.

Answer (score 1):

Install [mysql .net connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and add database.

Adding the database: **Add New Item** -> **Add Local Database** --> **Select Database** -> **New Connection** -> select datasource=Mysql databsae and enter username and password..

Everything else like SQL Server.

Comment: Thx for your reply I'll give it a try! I'll let you know if I reach my goal with it :)

Comment: I found out that the .NET connector is a powerfull tool. Just created a sample project in which it is the provider for a EDM. But with this connector it is still not possible to store a database with development data under source control. The only thing I found that it was possible to generate a DDL script.

Comment: i can test it, with more details and reply with more clear statment and example..